# REST call for fields: "Type cannot be null"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, 2016, pnpjs

I'm making rest calls to get a lists fields in a custom JS application. For some reason it's failing when I make the call through the app but when I do it in the console it works fine.

I'm using Pnpjs to make the calls, I've looked at the two requests and there's nothing different other than the `Request Headers` between when it's called in app vs console

[image]

This is my pnp.setup config:

```
$pnp.setup({
    sp: {
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    },
    defaultCachingStore: "session", // or "local"
    defaultCachingTimeoutSeconds: 30,
    globalCacheDisable: false, // or true to disable caching in case of debugging/testing
    enableCacheExpiration: true, // added in 2.0.8
    cacheExpirationIntervalMilliseconds: 1000 // added in 2.0.8
});
```

Comment: Can you try by removing the header config in your code ?

Comment: Hey, so I did try this but by default all my calls return with `application/json; odata=nometadata`. I trying to find a way in 2016 to return calls under `odata=verbose`

Comment: what version of pnp are you using ? also, can you try it as `$pnp.setup({
    sp: {
        headers: {
            "Accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    },` and check ? Notice the double quotes over `accept`

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.10. I know it's not the latest but I'm not aware of any changes to the newer version that impacts http heaaders and I can't update at the moment